# Opening PDF file after creating CFDocument

Tags: coldfusion

```
 <cfset filename = "c:\print" & ".pdf"> 

            <cfdocument 
                filename="#filename#" 
                overwrite="yes"
```

After creating a cfdocument and storing it in my file directory above. How do I open the document in the browser just after the cfdoc is created?

Comment: Side note, CF is multi-threaded. If multiple threads hit this code at the same time, they may not get the correct version of "c:\print.pdf".

Comment: yes this is the problem I seem to be haivng

Comment: Use something like a uuid to ensure file names are unique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really need to save it to a file *and* display it in the browser, use [`cfcontent`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-c/cfcontent.html) with the `file` attribute.

```
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=someFileName.pdf" />
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" file="#filename#" />
```

Otherwise, just omit `filename` from your cfdocument call. [Per the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c21.html):

> ... If you omit the `filename` attribute, ColdFusion displays the output
>   in the browser.